# can we add subscript and superscript buttons to a text editor using jquery in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

can we add subscript and superscript buttons to a text editor using jquery in html??
I have text editor which have buttons to make text bold, underlined, Italic, etc...,
but in my application I need to write text in subscript and superscript format.
answer me as soon as possible.
Thanks..

Comment: Which HTML text editor are you using? I believe there are more than 1 type of text editors for HTML, and some of them support sub/superscript by default, even if the option is somewhat hidden.

Comment: can you give more info about your application for example about its working and what it is for